# Inexplicable table error -- 'extra alignment tab' but I definitely have the right # columns; also overfull hbox

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm having an issue where LaTeX won't accept the main heading row of my table (the third row of code below). When I comment out that line, it works.
Here's the beginning of my tabular-

```
\begin{tabular}{r| >{\raggedleft}p{0.8cm} ||r|r| >{\raggedleft}p{0.8cm} || r|r| >{\raggedleft}p{0.8cm} |}
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Speaker A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Speaker B} \\ \hline
\small{Session-Part} & \small{Total length} & \small{Time} & \small{Time \%} & \small{DM rate} & \small{Time} & \small{Time \%} & \small{DM rate} \\
1-\textsc{chat} & 10:15 & 4:17 & 41.8\% &  & 4:38 & 45.2\% &  \\
```

I think that it is somehow not registering the linebreak, and I'm getting a bunch of overfull hbox errors with it (is it too long? it seems to fit otherwise...). If I try to put a \hline there it also gives me a misplaced noalign error. Otherwise if I try to run it as it is here, it gives me an 'extra alignment tab' error for the first '&' in the *next* row, so it thinks I haven't ended the row. I have counted the columns a zillion times and I cannot fathom what could be going wrong. Could it be a problem with the multicolumn format? Again, it works fine when I comment out the second row of headings, so :/

Comment: regardless `\small` is a switch it is not a macro that takes arguments.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Bad boxes arise because you have to narrow `p` columns.

Comment: I've tried making them narrower, and again the table still runs without that row with these p widths, so that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: `\raggedright` redefines `\\ ` so you either need `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ ` or use `\arraybackslash` to define it back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I slightly modified your table: (i) added new column type *with correct definition* (as shortcuts for simpler its typing), (ii) added new command for `\multicolumn` and (iii) increase width of table (which cause in yiur MWE warning `bad box: 2`. I also remove remedy of wrong use `\small` macro. Horizontal lines I left as they are used in your MWE.

With this modification I can't reproduce your problem nor get any warnings of bad boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\mcbf[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c||}{\textbf{#2}}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}\small
\begin{tabular}{r|P{1cm} ||r|r|P{0.8cm}||r|r|P{1cm}||}
\mcbf{2}{}
    & \mcbf{3}{Speaker A} & \mcbf{3}{Speaker B}    \\ 
    \hline
Session-Part 
    & Total length     & Time & Time \% & DM rate & Time & Time \% & DM rate \\
1-\textsc{chat} 
    & 10:15            & 4:17 & 41.8\%  &         & 4:38 & 45.2\%  &         \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
   \end{document}
```

The main difference in between my modification and your MWE is added `arraybackslash` to your definition of column  `p{...}`. Without this (at list in the last column of table} cause unexpected problems -- its missing in your MWE *is source of your problem*).
[image]